Why is my laptop screen going black on warm colors at 144 Hz?
I was playing metro exodus and when I died my screen went black suddenly. I didn't understand what the f just happened. Tried restarting it and for a moment it stood black. And then screen came back but with a constant black flickering. Then it stood still and when I open a white web page in fullscreen it went black again. The night light was on so I closed it and it no longer went black on white screens. And I wanted to test if the problem still occuring and tried opening color on full screen. In red, green, blue and cyan colors in fullscreen my screen is going black. If I open night light it goes black on white screen too. All this happened on 144hz. And when I change it to 60hz everything seemed normal. I tried updating my nvidia rtx 2070 drivers alas it didnt work. Everything was working perfect up until 2 hrs ago. When I was gaming my gpu was at 86 and cpu at 80 degrees. Now it revolves around 50. Any help is much appreciated.
Edit: I tried to open warm colors on fullscreen again after the laptop had cooled down but its still same.

@Gantendo I let it cool it overnight and tried to open warm colors again while its cool and its still same. So I dont think overheating is the problem here.

What is the laptop model? It may not support well 144hz.

@harrymc its monster tulpar t7 v19.7.  Its supporting Im sure of it.  Im suspecting that overheating fried something about the lcd panel. Sadly Im going to send it to the manufacturer.

I sent my laptop the manufacturer. According to them the LED panel's circuit breaker is going off when it cant bear the dense RGB colors on 144hz and thus shutting off the screen.
